# Amazon always asks for captcha while scraping it with Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape `amazon.com` but everytime I try to send a request to Amazon, I'm always getting a captcha error. I have never encountered such a problem before. I am using headers but still not getting results.

Here's my code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

# Create a session, set headers and send request
s = HTMLSession()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = s.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0001ARCFA', headers=headers)

# Render the site and sleep for 1 second
r.html.render(sleep=1)

# Get price and import fees
price = r.html.find('#price_inside_buybox')[0].text
importFees = r.html.find('#a-size-base a-color-secondary')[0].text

# Print the results
print('Price:', price)
print('Import Fees:', importFees)
```

And this is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\musta\Desktop\asdsa.py", line 8, in <module>
    price = r.html.find('#price_inside_buybox')[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But I want this:

```
Price: $69.00
Import Fees: + No Import Fees Deposit & $14.23 Shipping to Singapore
```

***(By the way, I was using Singapore VPN, that's why Amazon shows me Import Fees. You might not see any Import Fees on Amazon.)***

How am I gonna get the `price` results without dealing with `captcha`? Hope you guys understand what I meant.

Comment: Are you certain this is caused by a captcha? I can't see any evidence that that is the case.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Because when I print the code `r.html.render (sleep = 1) ', the page is asking me for a captcha. Also, the code only works once. For later attempts, Amazon is asking me for a captcha.